# Unable to load package information from registry: The "timeout" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('100000')

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-material

I'm getting this error while installing the angular material in my project

```
PS C:\Users\Avinash Kumar\Desktop\Projects\CRUD\Project 2\Library Management System\UI\UI\Frontend> ng add @angular/material
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✖ Unable to load package information from registry: The "timeout" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('100000')
```

My Angular, node and npm versions

- Angular CLI: 15.2.6
- Node: 18.16.0
- Package Manager: npm 9.5.1
- OS: win32 x64

Error result

[image]

Comment: Your nodejs is not compatible try installing nodejs 18.0.0 for angular version 15.2.6 see this guide https://angular.io/guide/versions

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing the version of Node and Angular and it's worked for me

Answer (score 2):

```
npm config set timeout
```

This will set timeout 0 and it worked for me. After this run

```
npm config list
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I changed the version of Angular and Node to below one
Angular CLI: 13.3.4
Node: 14.20.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.17
OS: win32 x64

After that I got another error

> Cannot find module @schematics/angular/private/components' Require stack: - C:\Users\Avinash Kumar\Desktop\Projects\CRUD\Project 2\Library Management System\UI\UI\Frontend\node_modules@angular\cli\models\schematic-engine-host.js

But after running the below command that error was also got resolved.
then after I downloaded the angular material successfully:

```
npm install @angular-devkit/schematics @angular-devkit/core @schematics/angular
```

Answer (score 0):

Also had a similar issue with ng-bootstrap.
Try running `npx ng add @angular/material`. This seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got resolved only by removing the ~/.npmrc