# Angular timeout error when trying to add a new package

Tags: node.js, angular

When I'm trying to add a new package (like `ng add @angular/material`) to my newly created angular project i get the following error:

```
Unable to load package information from registry: The "timeout" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('100000')
```

As pointed out in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76069908/unable-to-load-package-information-from-registry-the-timeout-argument-must-be), I know that this issue is caused because `angular` version is incompatible with `nodejs` version, however after looking at the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/versions) I found out that I have installed an `angular` version that is compatible with `nodejs`

Here is my `ng version`:

```
Angular CLI: 15.2.9
Node: 18.10.0
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 15.2.9
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.9
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.9
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.9
@schematics/angular             15.2.9
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      4.9.5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to load package information from registry: The "timeout" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('100000')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76069908/unable-to-load-package-information-from-registry-the-timeout-argument-must-be)